# Why getting different solutions by feeding constraint to fmincon in two similar way?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am using `fmincon` to solve a problem. The problem has some linear inequality constraints that are written in Matrix A and B. 
I can write these constraints in 2 way and I should get analogous results. But, weirdly I am getting different solutions. why is that?

1)  In the first way, I can feed the constraint to 'fmincon' function as follows:
`[Xsqp, FUN ,FLAG ,Options] = fmincon(@(X)SQP(X,Dat),X,A,B,[],[],lb,ub,@(X)SQPnolcon(X,Dat,A,B),options);

% I comment the line 'C=A*X'-B;'
in the function 'SQPnolcon' and put C=[] instead, because A and B are defined already in fmincon function`

2) As the second way I can write it like this:

`[Xsqp, FUN ,FLAG ,Options] = fmincon(@(X)SQP(X,Dat),X,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@(X)SQPnolcon(X,Dat,A,B),options);`
and also the constraint function as follows:

```
function [C,Ceq] = SQPnolcon(X,Dat,A,B)
C=A*X'-B;
Ceq = [];
end
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data as well, please.

Comment: I tried to add sample data but the data for A,B matrices are ridiculously huge. I am afraid I cannot write my real function here. @kkuilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first, you're supplying `A` and `B` as both linear inequality constraints and as nonlinear inequality constraints, but in the second you're only supplying them as nonlinear inequality constraints.

I get why you might expect that would be equivalent, since they're the same constraints anyway. But the linear equality constraints are applied in a different context than the nonlinear equality constraints, and that leads the optimization algorithm to find a different solution.

I'm afraid I'm not able to explain exactly *how* the two different types of constraints are applied, and at what points in the algorithm - and in any case, this would vary depending on which algorithm you're asking `fmincon` to use (active-set, trust-region and so on). For that level of detail, you might need to ask MathWorks. But the basic answer is that you're getting different results because you're asking the algorithm to do two different things.

Comment: In the first way,  I comment the line `C=A*X'-B;`
in the function `SQPnolcon` and put C=[ ] instead, because A and B are defined already in fmincon function. So in both methods, I define them one time. But in first method I define then as an linear inequality constraint and in second as nonlinear inequality constraint. this is the option i use for fmincon `options = optimset('Algorithm','active- set','Display','off');` should I ask my question in Mathwork forum?@sam-roberts Thank you for hints

Comment: OK - so in the first case you're supplying them as linear inequality constraints, and in the second you're supplying them as nonlinear inequality constraints. The answer is still the same - you're asking the algorithm to do two different things, so you're getting different answers. For more detail on the exact differences in the way `fmincon` treats linear and nonlinear inequality constraints, you'll need to ask an expert in `fmincon`. You might try MATLAB Answers, but that's very similar to StackOverflow; you could just call MathWorks directly and ask their advice.